Looking for Expertise in Validating Observation in Spring Boot Trace
I have a Spring Boot 3 application that is having web browser clocking issues when I run it at openjdk 17 and on a certain type of Linux server. I say certain type, because the same Spring Boot 3 application at openjdk 17 runs fine on other Linux servers that are at the same release as the server with the issue. One main difference between the servers that work and do not is different security requirements.
After running a Spring Boot trace, I think I might have narrowed the problem to a defect with the openjdk 17 synchronization logic and how it is interacting with this specific Linux server. I was hoping someone with Spring Boot developer logic in the nio-exec logic could help confirm my suspicion.
I recreated the web browser clocking issue with the following https socket connections from the web browser to the Spring Boot web server with the Spring Boot trace running (i.e. add --trace to the command line):
10.10.10.14 (Web Browser)

10.10.10.29 (Spring Boot web server)

10.10.10.14:42149 -> 10.10.10.29:9443

10.10.10.14:26045 -> 10.10.10.29:9443

In the Spring Boot trace, I only see these records for the 42149 and 26045 ports:

2024-08-13T08:14:03.835-05:00 DEBUG 2117389 --- [nio-9443-exec-7] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint
$NioSocketWrapper@3c3b81b1:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@a2e78b4:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.10.10.29:9443 remote=/10.10.10.14:42149]]
2024-08-13T08:14:03.836-05:00 DEBUG 2117389 --- [nio-9443-exec-8] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3c3b81b1:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@a2e78b4:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.10.10.29:9443 remote=/10.10.10.14:42149]]
2024-08-13T08:14:03.836-05:00 DEBUG 2117389 --- [nio-9443-exec-9] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3c3b81b1:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@a2e78b4:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.10.10.29:9443 remote=/10.10.10.14:42149]]

2024-08-13T08:15:03.857-05:00 DEBUG 2117389 --- [nio-9443-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@3b018c7e].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3c3b81b1:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@a2e78b4:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.10.10.29:9443 remote=/10.10.10.14:42149]])

2024-08-13T08:14:03.599-05:00 DEBUG 2117389 --- [nio-9443-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@2f0318da:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2b8cf37c:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.10.10.29:9443 remote=/10.10.10.14:26045]]
2024-08-13T08:14:03.599-05:00 DEBUG 2117389 --- [nio-9443-exec-6] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@2f0318da:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2b8cf37c:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.10.10.29:9443 remote=/10.10.10.14:26045]]

2024-08-13T08:15:03.857-05:00 DEBUG 2117389 --- [nio-9443-exec-4] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@3b018c7e].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@2f0318da:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2b8cf37c:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.10.10.29:9443 remote=/10.10.10.14:26045]])

When I compare this trace data to https sockets that work, I see this difference.

https sockets that work

There is only one nio-exec thread that registers read interest, there are nio-exec threads that register write interest, and then there is reading data from the socket.

https sockets that have the web browser clocking issue (listed in trace records above)

There are multiple nio-exec threads that register read interest within the 1 millisecond range. There is then no write interest registration or reading from the socket, and the socket is closed 60 seconds later with the default server.tomcat.keep-alive-timeout setting.
My hypothesis here is that there is some type of openjdk 17 synchronization defect that is allowing multiple nio-exec threads to read register within the same millisecond. This then causes the nio-exec logic to get into a state where it stalls and stops reading from the https socket. Can someone with Spring Boot developer knowledge with the nio-exec logic let me know if I am on the right track here?
